# Discord embed being sent before image loads from external URL

Tags: python, async-await, discord.py

This is what I need, but Discord.py sends out the embed before the image is even loaded. Another problem I have is that I could technically fetch the image and save it as a physical image itself, but I did not see anything in the Discord embed docs about being able to attach an actual image. (not one from a URL link).

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
planetUrl = "https://app.pixelencounter.com/api/basic/planets?frame=1000&disableBackground=true&disableStars=true"
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    embed.set_thumbnail(
        url = planetUrl
    )
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

client.run(token)
```

This is what I tried to solve this issue:

```
async def fetchImage():
    pixelPlanetUrl = requests.get("https://app.pixelencounter.com/api/basic/planets?frame=1000&disableBackground=true&disableStars=true")
    return pixelPlanetUrl
image = fetchImage()

    await image
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

but to no success. Any suggestions would be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: You can attach local images to an embed: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#local-image

Answer (score 0):

There is a link to the FAQ explaining how to use a image you are locally storing in the documentation of the `set_thumbnail` function. You need to load your image using `discord.File` and then use its attachment url as `url`. More on that can be read [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#local-image). Here is a simple example:

```
file = discord.File("path/to/my/image.png", filename="image.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://image.png")
await message.channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```